# Retrieving data in php

Tags: php

I've created a page where I've place for updating the attachment. While doing so, if a file with same name, size, extension is attached, the attachment table need not be updated. This is the scenario. This is how I tried to do:

```
  else if($mode == "attachment_update") {
            $id = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST["_id"]));
            $upload_directory = "upload/attachment/";
            $result = file_upload("attachment", "../".$upload_directory);

            $file_name = '".addslashes($result[file_name])."';
write_log($file_name);
            $file_extension = '".$result[file_extension]."';
write_log($file_extension);
            $file_size = '".$result[file_size]."';
write_log($file_size);
            $uploaded_file_name = '".$result[uploaded_file_name]."';
write_log($uploaded_file_name);
            $uploaded_file_path = '".$upload_directory.$result[uploaded_file_name]."';
write_log($uploaded_file_path);

            $query_select = "SELECT
                              file_name,
                              file_extension,
                              file_size,
                              uploaded_file_name,
                              uploaded_file_path
                            FROM
                              attachments
                            WHERE
                              id = 'id';";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_select) or throwexception(mysqli_error($mysqli));                 
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);

            write_log($row[0]);
            write_log($row[1]);
            write_log($row[2]);
            write_log($row[3]);
            write_log($row[4]);


            if($row[0] == $file_name && 
               $row[1] == $file_extension && 
               $row[2] == $file_size && 
               $row[3] == $uploaded_file_name && 
               $row[4] == $uploaded_file_path) 
            { 
                write_log("inside if"); 
            } else {
                if($result[status] == true) {
                        $query = "UPDATE
                                  attachments
                                SET
                                  file_name = '".addslashes($result[file_name])."',
                                  file_extension = '".$result[file_extension]."',
                                  file_size = '".$result[file_size]."',
                                  uploaded_file_name = '".$result[uploaded_file_name]."',
                                  uploaded_file_path = '".$upload_directory.$result[uploaded_file_name]."',
                                  recorded_by = '$recorded_by',
                                  recorded_datetime = '$recorded_datetime'
                                WHERE
                                  id = 'id';";
                        mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or throwexception(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                    }
            }


            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Updated successfully"));
            exit;
        }
```

The if condition does the thing. If all are true, the table will not be updated. If even any one fails, the table will be updated.

Here the problem is $file_name, $file_extension, $file_size, $uploaded_file_name are going null. I don't know how to retrieve it. Can someone tell how to retrieve those data, so that if can check it with the if condition?

Comment: does any record exist in the database with same id which you are trying to update

Comment: Why do you have something like this '".addslashes($result[file_name])."'; in quotes (in the beginning where you define $file_name)

Comment: @dharmendrachaudhary: Yes. The previously attached file will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, You do not need to fire select query. just add `AND` condition in update query.

```
if ($mode == "attachment_update") {
    $id = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST["_id"]));
    $upload_directory = "upload/attachment/";
    $result = file_upload("attachment", "../" . $upload_directory);

    $file_name = '".addslashes($result[file_name])."';
    write_log($file_name);
    $file_extension = '".$result[file_extension]."';
    write_log($file_extension);
    $file_size = '".$result[file_size]."';
    write_log($file_size);
    $uploaded_file_name = '".$result[uploaded_file_name]."';
    write_log($uploaded_file_name);
    $uploaded_file_path = '".$upload_directory.$result[uploaded_file_name]."';
    write_log($uploaded_file_path);

    $query = "UPDATE
                          attachments
                        SET
                          file_name = '" . addslashes($result[file_name]) . "',
                          file_extension = '" . $result[file_extension] . "',
                          file_size = '" . $result[file_size] . "',
                          uploaded_file_name = '" . $result[uploaded_file_name] . "',
                          uploaded_file_path = '" . $upload_directory . $result[uploaded_file_name] . "',
                          recorded_by = '$recorded_by',
                          recorded_datetime = '$recorded_datetime'
                        WHERE
                          id = 'id'
                          and file_name <> '" . addslashes($result[file_name]) . "',
                          and file_extension = '" . $result[file_extension] . "',
                          and file_size = '" . $result[file_size] . "',
                          and uploaded_file_name = '" . $result[uploaded_file_name] . "',
                          and uploaded_file_path = '" . $upload_directory . $result[uploaded_file_name] . "',
;";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or throwexception(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Updated successfully"));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That's fine, it's working good. If I have to retrieve the data in this way for those variables, how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your question need more clarity.

> Can you share the function,
>   $result = file_upload("attachment", "../".$upload_directory);

Are you able to log the values of $filename and $row?

> write_log($file_name);

AND

> write_log($row[0]);

Comment: While logging those I get the value of #row[0], but the value of $file_name I'm getting is zero.